# Free Unix/Linux Guest Login

Tags: unix, login

Is there any free *nix guest/guest terminal login without a need to register in order to use it ?

Comment: I smell an unfilled niche.

Comment: Filled. http://www.red-pill.eu/freeunix.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a free, anonymous *nix shell account would pose a hugh security risk, and I do not know of any. I would either ask a trusted friend, or if you are interested in learning more about it, install [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) on a [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) VM.

Answer (score 3):

Quite honestly, I can't imagine anyone being crazy enough to grant anonymous guest logins on a public system. Do as Dave suggests and create a virtual machine to play with. This probably belongs on Super User by the way.

Comment: Someone's crazy enough to give away the root password to one of their machines http://www.coker.com.au/selinux/play.html - except it's running SELinux, so there's very little risk.

Comment: Ok, so I have a limited imagination.

Answer (score 1):

sdf in Dallas used to be a 4 line dial-in publicly accessible Unix system. It's been many years, but don't give up. Use google and be diligent and flexible in your keywords. You're probably asking in the wrong forum.

believe it or not, SDF still exists with the same philosophy and goals.

http://www.sdf.org/

Answer (score 1):

Ask Google and ye shall receive:
["The biggest Free Shell list on the net :-)"](http://www.red-pill.eu/freeunix.shtml)